# How to create object tag for IE with JQ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I need to add `<object>` tag to HTML. It works fine in all browsers except IE, which throws a lot of errors like:

- SyntaxError: Expected ']'
- Error: Invalid argument.
- TypeError: 'currentStyle' is null or not an object (this is when i try to create only plain `<object>` with no params)

My code is:

```
jQuery('<object/>').attr('type', 'application/x-fb-vlc').append([
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'windowless', 'value': 'true'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'autoplay', 'value': 'true'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'bgcolor', 'value': '#999999'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'network-caching', 'value': '1000'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'adjust-filter', 'value': 'true'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'marquee-filter', 'value': 'true'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'logo-filter', 'value': 'true'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'native-scaling', 'value': 'true'}),
    jQuery('<param/>').attr({
        'name': 'src', 
        'value': 'http://' + response.server + '&_=' + (new Date().getTime())
    })
]).appendTo(camera_div);
```

I also tried other methods like `append` and etc.

Is there any solution to add this except plain HTML?

Comment: try to put this code in only one line

Comment: @Cherniv How would that help? As far as I know Arrays and Objects don't mind multiple lines.

Comment: @Broxzier yes but explorer' html renderer does mind sometimes

Comment: I see nothing wrong in the code. The only thing I can think of is `new Date().getTime()` which returns a Number. JavaScript should just append it to the string, but maybe IE10 has some issues with this.

Comment: @Cherniv http://i.imgflip.com/25f0b.jpg

Comment: Have you tried without the array, just passing the newly created param elements as comma-separated single parameters?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy , exactly !

Comment: @Cherniv dude I see you everywhere on SO these days!

Comment: @AhmadAlfy cause i got something boring to do at work. so i'm here ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have just copy pasted your code in fiddle with few changes. Its not throwing any error.

```
jQuery('<object/>').attr('type', 'application/x-fb-vlc').append([
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'windowless', 'value': 'true'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'autoplay', 'value': 'true'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'bgcolor', 'value': '#999999'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'network-caching', 'value': '1000'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'adjust-filter', 'value': 'true'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'marquee-filter', 'value': 'true'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'logo-filter', 'value': 'true'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({'name': 'native-scaling', 'value': 'true'}),
jQuery('<param/>').attr({
    'name': 'src', 
    'value': ''
})
]).appendTo("#camera_div");
```

Please look my given **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HWu6G/)**.I am using IE 9.